# Get values from under different keys in JSON with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

When I have an following JSON,

```json
{
  "group1": [
    {
      "name": "name_AAA",
      "size": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "name_BBB",
      "size": 2
    }
  ],
  "group2": [
    {
      "name": "name_CCC",
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "name_DDD",
      "size": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get following values with `jq` command.

```
name_AAA
name_BBB
name_CCC
name_DDD
```

I tried following but returned unexpected value.

```
$ jq -r '.group1[] * .group2[] | .name' < "mydata.json"
name_CCC
name_CCC
name_DDD
name_DDD
```

How can I get value which I wanted??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
jq -r '.[][].name' mydata.json
```

along with `Raw Output` option to get rid of wrapper quotes

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YK2L5Q-_6b3)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you quick answer!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You might also wish to consider:

```
jq -r '..|.name?' mydata.json
```